# Multiplying the user's input with a decimal

Tags: java, user-interface, decimal, actionevent

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
     float x, y;
     if(ae.getSource()==z) {
         x= Float.parseFloat(a.getText());
         y= x*x*3.14;
         Boomer.setText(String.valueOf(y)); 
     }
 }
```

I'm making a multiplication GUI. I've made a couple of these before, but this one is slightly different.This one differs because I'm specifically allowing the user to find the area of a circle by inputting the radius.

I simply wrote this code like any other basic mathematical function-related programs, but I specified the equation for the circle's area. This is where the issue comes in. The program can't work when I specify that a decimal must be used to find the output. If I were to tell it to do x*x*10, for instance, it works fine. I can only assume the issue stems from the decimal.

Comment: So what happens when you don't do `x*x*10`, and use a decimal such as `x*x*3.14`? Do you get an error message or do you get a value?

Comment: Here's the error message I get:
BaffleGUI.java:39: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to float

Comment: Okay, so I think you could do zachjack's answer or simply convert the 3.14 to a float like this: `y=x*x*(float)3.14;` and the error should go away (if you don't care about the "lossy conversion").

Comment: Both your suggestion and his worked fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is obvious that 3.14 is a double value. Thus, the following line ensamples incompatible types. It tries to put double 3.14 into float pi.

```
float pi = 3.14;
```

This is one possible way:

```
float pi = 3.14f;
```

This is another one:

```
float pi = (float) 3.14;
```

You should take zachjack's advice to get precise result. Math.PI corresponds to double as well. Thus, you should calculate area using this line:

```
y = x * x * (float) Math.PI;
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that 3.14 is being being compiled as a Double and not a Float.

I would recommend using `Math.PI` instead of just 3.14 and then change the values to Doubles. That should fix any issues.

Answer (score 0):

You could change this line `y= x*x*3.14;` to this `y= x*x*(float)3.14;`.